# Ordering a List of Strings with spaces in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to order a list of strings in python based on the spaces between them. For instance if the list of strings are `{'hello world', 'hello', 'hello world again', 'hello there'}.`

After ordering, the list should contain the string with the highest number of spaces in the first position and others subsequently:

```
{'hello world again', 'hello world', 'hello there', 'hello'}.
```

Regards,
Alok

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You've described your problem very well, but you've missed a key element of Stack Overflow's question-and-answer format: What is your question?

Comment: OK, interesting idea. Have you heard of the `key` parameter that you can pass to `sort()`?

Comment: wait, why does your list start and end with curly braces?

Comment: Aside: calling something a list and then using `{` and `}` to enclose it is confusing, because that syntax would define a *set* in Python.

Comment: What should be done when two strings have the same number of spaces?

Comment: Typo there, I got the solution: words.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(y.count(' '), x.count(' ')))

Comment: What is you have tabs?

Answer (score 5):

for `list`:

```
>>> list.sort(key=lambda x: x.count(' '), reverse=True)
# list = ['hello world again', 'hello world', 'hello there', 'hello']
```

for `set`:

```
>>> sorted(set, key=lambda x: x.count(' '), reverse=True)
# ['hello world again', 'hello world', 'hello there', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is **set** or **list**,You can use `sum` as key to `sorted` function-

```
d={'hello world', 'hello', 'hello world again', 'hello there'}
sorted(d,key = lambda x: sum(1 for space in d if space==" "))
```

OR

```
lst = ['hello world again', 'hello world', 'hello there', 'hello']
sorted(d,key = lambda x: sum(1 for space in l if space==" "))
```

Output-

```
['hello world again', 'hello world', 'hello there', 'hello']
```

Comment: words.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(y.count(' '), x.count(' ')))

Answer (score -1):

The best is to provide your own `cmp` argument to `.sort()` or `sorted()`

```
>>> s = ['a', 'a a', 'a b', 'ba', 'a b a']
>>> s.sort(cmp= lambda x,y: -cmp(x.count(' '), y.count(' ')) or cmp(x,y))
>>> s
['a b a', 'a a', 'a b', 'a', 'ba']
```

Answer (score -1):

simple solution:

```
ll = ['hello world again', 'hello world', 'hello there', 'hello']
sorted(ll,reverse=True)

['hello world again', 'hello world', 'hello there', 'hello']
```

you don't need lambda or anything - its the normal sort order